# How to get json response using alamofire in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, codable

I have been trying to get json response from url using alamofire. Created model, apirouter and api client class.

its shows error

```
 failure(Alamofire.AFError.responseSerializationFailed(reason: 
  Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.decodingFailed(error: 
   Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "variables", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"variables\", intValue: nil) (\"variables\").", underlyingError: nil)))))
```

Here is my postman json response:

```
   [
{
    "id": "00602c70-fc8a-11e9-ad1d-2abe2670111d",
    "resourceType": "Task",
    "name": "My Tasks",
    "owner": null,
    "query": {
        "assigneeExpression": "${currentUser()}",
        "taskVariables": [],
        "processVariables": [],
        "caseInstanceVariables": [],
        "orQueries": []
    },
    "properties": {
        "variables": [
            {
                "name": "loanAmount",
                "label": "Loan Amount"
            },
            {
                "name": "firstName",
                "label": "First Name"
            }
        ],
        "color": "#555555",
        "showUndefinedVariable": false,
        "description": "Tasks assigned to me",
        "refresh": false,
        "priority": -10
      }
    }
   ]
```

My trying get values for **id, name and properties -> variables -> name and label** from json response.

Here is model class:

```
  import Foundation

public struct Filter: Codable {

let id: String
let name: String
let properties: [variables]


}

public struct variables: Codable {

   let name: String
   let label: String

}
```

Here is code for alamofire :

```
    private static func performRequest<T:Decodable>(route:APIRouter, decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder(), completion:@escaping (AFResult<T>)->Void) -> DataRequest {

    return AF.request(route)
                    .responseDecodable (decoder: decoder){ (response: AFDataResponse<T>) in
                        completion(response.result)
                        print("framework response::",response.result)


    }


}


  public static func getFilter(completion:@escaping (AFResult<[Filter]>)->Void) {
       let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
    performRequest(route: APIRouter.getFilter, decoder: jsonDecoder, completion: completion)
   }
```

Any help much appreciates pls...

Comment: You are missing the step `"properties"` in your JSON before accessing `"variables"`. Either use a custom init, or use a Properties struct between.

Comment: initially i have properties too but same error came..

Comment: Tip: When having issue with JSON Codable/Encodable, do the reverse, you'll see what JSON is expecting your code, and can compare with the one you have: https://pastebin.com/TREcv2zF (based on initial code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your model class should be like the below.

```
import Foundation

public struct Filter: Codable {

let id: String
let name: String
let properties: Properties


}

public struct Properties: Codable {
   let variables: [variables]
   let color: String
   let showUndefinedVariable: Bool
   let description: String
   let refresh: Bool
   let priority: Int

}

public struct variables: Codable {

   let name: String
   let label: String

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this one? This is what it should be

```
public struct Filter: Codable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let properties: Property
}

public struct Property: Codable {
    let variables: [Variable]
}

public struct Variable: Codable {
    let name: String
    let label: String

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're getting is pretty clear: `No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"variables\"`

You're attempting to decode the JSON into the `Filter` struct, but the JSON has no `variables` property. You could fix this by introducing a new `Properties` struct that will wrap the `variables` property, like this:

```
struct Filter: Codable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let properties: Properties
}

struct Properties: Codable {
    let variables: Variables
}

struct Variables: Codable {
    let name: String
    let label: String
}
```

Also, as you'll see in this snippet, it's convention to make the write the type names in CamelCase, so `struct Variables` instead of `struct variables`.

Comment: still facing same error failure(Alamofire.AFError.responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.decodingFailed(error: Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "properties", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil)))))

Comment: This will not work because `properties` is not an array, it's an object. see the JSON carefully.